# Second differential equals implies functions are equals

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, multivariable-calculus

I was faced by this question a while ago and I can't proceed: Let $f,g:A \to \Bbb{R} $ be two functions with first and second derivatives, $A$ a connected open of $\Bbb{R}^n$. I need to show that if for some $a \in A$, $f(a)=g(a)$, $df(a)=dg(a)$ and $\forall x \in A$ $d^2f(x)=d^2g(x)$, then $f=g$.

Actually I don't know how to use all the properties to achieve the result, since I'm not used to work with differentials.

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Taylor's theorem maybe?

Comment: Actually I think I've got: Let $h=f-g$. Well, $d^2 h = 0$, so $dh$ is constant; but $d h(a)=0$, so $dh(x)=0$, for all $x\in U$. So, $h$ is constant. Then, as $h(a)=0$, it is $0$ for all $x \in U$, as we wanted. Seems right, @copper.hat?

Comment: If it is, I will make an answer!

Comment: Well, that is a good approach, but you need to fill in the details, for example connectivity is important.

Comment: One thing that is not essential but can simplify the proof is that $h$ is actually $C^2$.